# Using empty tuple as default iterable argument in function

Tags: python

Are there any downsides to using an empty tuple as a default for an iterable argument to a function? Assuming that what you want in the function is an immutable iterable.
e.g.

```
def foo(a, b=()):
  print a
  for x in b:
    print x
```

I can't seem to find many examples of this use case.

Comment: Does the function do anything outside of the `for` loop?

Comment: No, I'm assuming that what you want in the function is an immutable iterable.

Comment: Am I missing something?  The only way that the default argument would be used is if you manually call `foo` without arguments, as `foo()`.  But if you know the function only does anything if the iterable is nonempty, why would you ever write that?

Comment: I changed the example to make it more interesting. Basically I don't want foo() to cause an exception if I only pass other args.

Comment: Note that *all* invocations of the function shares the object in default argument. So a mutable object in default argument may get modified and cause error. I guess using a immutable tuple here is harmless.

Comment: .. and now you've edited the function so it *does* do something outside the `for` loop, which means your answer "No" to my question should really have been "Yes, my function does do things other than the for loop"..

Comment: I misunderstood your first question, sorry about that.
Either way, I think the core of the question is whether or not empty tuple's work as default arguments without any unintended side effects.

Comment: This is actually pretty useful for anyone who uses `click` since a "multiple" arg that's optional is passed as an empty tuple rather than `None`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can't think of any downsides, for when you need an immutable iterable. I think it just isn't used because the `default_list=None` and `default_list = default_list or None` pattern is what is used for mutable iterables, and people don't bother to change it (as there is no real need) in the less frequently occuring cases when the iterable is immutable. There is certainly no unexpected behaviour as with mutable default arguments.

Answer (score 6):

There are no intrinsic problems with designing your default to be an immutable empty tuple. However, it could be considered an non-intuitive design approach. Any references to specific locations in the tuple would cause an exception to be raised. If you are careful enough with creating argument checks then this will not be a problem, but if you build the rest of your code to expect data from specific locations and don't verify the tuple is empty then this will cause errors.

It depends on what your goal is for the argument. An empty list would have more obvious applications for a default argument (at least those that modify the list in some way), but an empty immutable tuple would not have any intuitive uses as a default besides indicating that no argument was given.

The typical approach for default arguments would be to set them to *None* which makes it perfectly clear when the arguments have not been set:

```
def foo(a, b=None):
```